# The field does not exist in the current context in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

Please assist with problem. I have asp.net application. On *.aspx file I have `<asp:TextBox ID="txtemail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>` code behind is `cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_newemp values('"txtemail.Text"')", con);`. When I try to compile my solution I got following error

```
The name 'txtemail' does not exist in the current context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-click on the page, in the solution explorer, and there is an option, something like "Convert to Web Application", which will regenerate your designer file.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_newemp values('" + txtemail.Text + "')", con);
```

However, you really should definitely use a parameter

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_newemp values(@p0)", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p0", GetType(String).Value = txtemail.Text;
```

Something like that.

Comment: the problem is in unsuccessful compilation of project.In code behind I can't access to field `txtemail` which exist on my page.

Comment: Copy most of the markup (minus the header) and copy the code.  Delete the page, readd it, and copy teh content back in.  Also, check the designer file and make sure there is a definition of that control, and that everything in the page is setup correctly (@Page header is correct, pages link correctly, etc.)

Comment: If there is no txtemail variable in the designer.cs, add a protected variable of type TextBox with the same name to your code behind. Also, Brian's suggestion is very important - your code is very open to SQL injection if you do not parameterize your queries and/or sanitize your input.